# Is it good to downvote answer to get another answer up?

Tags: discussion

This is the situation. There is a very old question and there is NO accepted answer.

There are two answers for that question.

Answer 01 has 30 up votes and answer 2 has 25 up votes.

My opinion is, answer 2 is the better answer and it is upto date.

So I upvoted it. And according to my opinion it should be in the first place. That type of situation, is down voting first answer is a good or bad idea?

I am again saying first answer is not wrong, but I think second is better than first answer.

Comment: You are comparing two answers and giving your own opinion . It may be possible that answer 1 will be helpful to others. So As per my suggestion .don't give the downvote just give the upvote which is helpful to you.

Comment: You should only downvote the answer if you feel it is not correct/has problems in one way or another, not because you really want to give another answer +2

Comment: @NickA You should vote on whether or not an answer is *useful*, not whether or not it's correct.  Lots of correct answers aren't useful.

Comment: @Servy if it's correct then it solves the problem at which point it's useful, surely?

Comment: @NickA No. Lots of correct answers aren't useful.  It might not answer the question, even if it contains correct information, it might be so unclear that it's not understandable, even if there's correct information in there somewhere, it might be off topic, it might have security vulnerabilities, it might be using bad practices, it might just be repeating the content of another answer, or even plagiarizing content (whether another answer or something else), just repeating content already readily available, it could be incomplete, it could go on lots of tangents, making the answer hard to find.

Comment: @Servy hence I said "not correct/*has problems in one way or another*", that second part includes quite a lot of possibilities, I made the comment from my phone which restricted the amount of things that I wanted to mention, although you've made quite a substantial list of them right there

Comment: @NickA If you realize that being correct isn't what's important, but rather is being a useful/helpful answer, then *say that*.  Don't say that people should vote on the correctness of an answer if that's not what they should actually be voting on.

Comment: @Servy I don't think either alone is what should be voted on but both together, although the way I wrote it was probably not the most clear, I think we've cleared that up, my main point was not to downvote one answer, just because you want another answer to be bumped up

Comment: @NickA Whether an answer is correct or incorrect *affects how useful it is*, but at the end of the day, you should *just* be voting on whether or not the post is useful.

Comment: @Servy Well I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on that

Comment: @NickA So you think that the correctness of an answer has no affect on it's usefulness?  You think that a correct answer and an incorrect answer are equally useful?  That...makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Servy No, I'm saying an incorrect answer is not useful, you can have plenty answer offering methods to do something but if they ultimately don't answer the OPs question, they're unhelpful. It sounded like you were arguing that an incorrect answer can be useful, although it doesn't help the OP

Comment: @NickA I would say that an incorrect answer can occasionally be useful (for example, a simple typo in a method name would make an answer not even compile, but such a small error often isn't problematic enough to make the answer as a whole not useful, as the error is so easy to find and fix).  But anyway, if you think that the correctness affects the usefulness then *you don't disagree with me* and you feel that people should be voting entirely on the usefulness of the answer, realizing that correctness (among other things) affects usefulness.

Comment: @Servy It seems to me that we're using different meanings for correct "a simple typo in a method name would make an answer not even compile, but such a small error often isn't problematic enough to make the answer as a whole not useful" this (assuming it pointed in the right direction, not arbitrarily wrong code) *is still correct* whether or not it compiles is irrelevant.

Comment: @NickA An answer that doesn't answer the question asked and makes provably incorrect statements wouldn't meet the definition of "correct".  The incorrect statements may often not be important, may be easily fixed, and may not make the answer not useful, but if they're making statements that are provably not true, then you can't still say it's "correct".  You *can* still say it's a useful/good/quality answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should vote based on the correctness, content and the quality of the answer, regardless of other answers.

If the answer was helpful for you and you think it's correct, please do so. But **don't** downvote another answer just because you prefer the other one.

Comment: Why in the world would you ignore highly relevant context, such as the quality of other answers?  Other answers *dramatically* affect the usefulness of any given answer, so ignoring that is *ignoring relevant information in determining the quality of the answer*.

Comment: @Servy I highly disagree. Others answers might be better or worst, but they won't affect my decision on whether to downvote or upvote *other* answers.

Comment: But they affect the usefulness of the answer, so the only way that the other answers wouldn't affect your vote is if you're not actually voting on the usefulness of the answer, contrary to the guidelines of what voting is actually there for.

Answer (score 4):

You should not consider the relative positions of answers in how you vote - the better answers should naturally find their way to the top over time on the basis that more people find it useful and upvote it compared to the other answer.

You can by all means upvote only the most useful answer of the lot, but downvote how you would if the other answer weren't there.

- If you feel that the answer (in isolation) is not useful and deserves a downvote, downvote it.
- If it's useful (in isolation), don't downvote it.
- If it's useful, but *not quite* as useful as the other answer, you might even consider upvoting it.

---

The obvious exception here is someone just copying another answer after a few hours or more without improving it in any way. But "without improving it" is important (and not always easy to judge) - sometimes another phrasing can clarify things or provide a better explanation to some.

But this probably isn't what you're referring to (as an answer that really don't contribute anything else is unlikely to end up above its counterpart).

Comment: `the better answers should naturally find their way to the top over time on the basis that more people find it useful and upvote it compared to the other answer` Not if you're telling people to upvote an answer that's not useful, which you are doing.

Comment: @Servy Answers that are similar but different can both be useful, it's not always a case of one-answer-to-rule-them-all. I didn't say upvote non-useful answers (at least not after I edited...).

Comment: Sure.  In such as situation you're arguing that the answer is useful *when considered in the context of all of the answers present*.  If that's the case, by all means, upvote it.  But if the answer *isn't* useful, then you shouldn't be upvoting it, and you're arguing that if the answer *isn't* useful when posted alongside other answers, then that fact should be ignored.

Answer (score -5):

If the answer isn't useful, when considering the context that it exists in, then you should downvote it.  If, because of the existence of the other answer, this answer provides nothing of value, then it's not a helpful answer, and you should vote accordingly.  If the answer is useful *even considering the other answers*, and provides helpful information *above and beyond what other answers are providing* (or conveys the information more effectively), then you should of course upvote the answer because it is useful, even if it's less useful than another answer.

Comment: Downvoting accidental redundancy (as opposed to intentional redundancy or redundancy through carelessness) would do more to alienate good answerers than it would help improve the site - answers further down don't really do much harm. Unfortunately most users aren't robots yet and getting downvotes has been known to be unpleasant for them. Now if we were deleting such answers (but not removing the reputation gained), that's something I can get behind.

Comment: @Dukeling Pretending that answers are useful when they're not, or ignoring the fact that answers aren't useful, is a way to remove quality from the site.  Actively encouraging people to vote *contrary* to the quality of a post, is *by definition* a way to lower quality.  When you create a world where people refuse to downvote unhelpful content out of fear that people may be upset that their unhelpful content was marked as unhelpful, then *people will keep posting unhelpful content*, and they won't fix their unhelpful content to make it helpful, and *the site's quality goes down.

Comment: @Dukeling Saying that we want to make people feel good about posting unhelpful answers, or they'll stop posting unhelpful answers, is saying *that you want more unhelpful answers*.  If the people are actually good answerers then they either won't post unhelpful answers, will fix them when they're marked as unhelpful (and be glad that they were given the feedback that they needed fixing), or be glad to remove the unhelpful content (if they can't fix it), because they care about the site's quality.  Encouraging people to keep bad answers as is isn't helpful.

Comment: There's a difference between downvoting a high-quality well-written answer written by a well-meaning user that was useful at the time of writing (but isn't any more exclusively due to a better answer) and downvoting an answer that was at no point useful. In the long term, wouldn't site quality go down if you "punish" users ("punish" in quotes for obvious reasons) for posting useful answers and they stop contributing due to that?

Comment: @Dukeling Downvotes aren't a way to punish users, they're a way to indicate the quality of an answer.  When you choose to not actually consider the quality of an answer when voting on it, then you're saying you want to *lower* the quality of the content of the site.  LIke I said before, if someone is actually a good answerer, they should be editing their answer to fix it if it's no longer useful, or would *want* to remove it if it's no longer useful, although they can't do so if people don't properly indicate that it's not useful, nor can other readers identify which answers are useful.

Comment: @Dukeling Someone coming and searching for an answer to their question doesn't care what answers *used* to be useful, they care which answers *are* useful.  Have some consideration for *them* (which is the people the votes are actually there for, after all), rather than only considering the feelings of the person who has an unhelpful answer, at the expense of *everyone else*.

Comment: Order is determined by voting, but you should not use voting as a means to establish your preferred ordering. You should not upvote an answer to give it visibility, and you should not downvote an answer to reduce its visibility.

Comment: @NicolBolas Where did I say otherwise?  I said that you should vote on answers based on how useful they are, as opposed to the other answers here indicating that you shouldn't actually vote on posts based on how useful they are (which indicate that you should voted based on how useful the answer is in a hypothetical alternate universe where there are no other answers, instead of voting based on how useful the answer *actually is*).